# The fastest way to check if some records in a database table?

Tags: database, oracle, hibernate

I have a huge table to work with . I want to check if there are some records whose parent_id equals my passing value . 
currently what I implement this is by using "select count(*) from mytable where parent_id = :id"; if the result > 0 , means the they do exist.

Because this is a very huge table , and I don't care what's the exactly number of records that exists , I just want to know whether it exists , so I think count(*) is a bit inefficient.

How do I implement this requirement in the fastest way ? I am using Oracle 10.

#

According to hibernate Tips & Tricks https://www.hibernate.org/118.html#A2

It suggests to write like this :

Integer count = (Integer) session.createQuery("select count(*) from ....").uniqueResult();

I don't know what's the magic of uniqueResult() here ? why does it make this fast ?

Compare to "select 1 from mytable where parent_id = passingId and rowrum < 2 " , which is more efficient ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An EXISTS query is the one to go for if you're not interested in the number of records:

```
select 'Y' from dual where exists (select 1 from mytable where parent_id = :id)
```

This will return 'Y' if a record exists and nothing otherwise.

[In terms of your question on Hibernate's "uniqueResult" - all this does is return a single object when there is only one object to return - instead of a set containing 1 object. If multiple results are returned the method throws an exception.]

Comment: You don't even need to query DUAL - `select 'Y' from mytable where parent_id = :id AND ROWNUM = 1` gives identical results.

Comment: Yep - just don't like "ROWNUM = 1" - doesn't feel as transparent as an EXISTS query. Just me though.

Answer (score 5):

There's no real difference between:

```
select 'y' 
  from dual 
 where exists (select 1 
                 from child_table 
                where parent_key = :somevalue)
```

and

```
select 'y' 
  from mytable 
 where parent_key = :somevalue 
   and rownum = 1;
```

... at least in Oracle10gR2 and up.  Oracle's smart enough in that release to do a FAST DUAL operation where it zeroes out any real activity against it.  The second query would be easier to port if that's ever a consideration.

The real performance differentiator is whether or not the parent_key column is indexed.  If it's not, then you should run something like:

```
select 'y' 
  from dual 
 where exists (select 1 
                 from parent_able 
                where parent_key = :somevalue)
```

Answer (score 5):

select count(*) should be lighteningly fast if you have an index, and if you don't, allowing the database to abort after the first match won't help much.

But since you asked:

```
boolean exists = session.createQuery("select parent_id from Entity where parent_id=?")
                        .setParameter(...)
                        .setMaxResults(1)
                        .uniqueResult() 
                 != null;
```

(Some syntax errors to be expected, since I don't have a hibernate to test against on this computer)

For Oracle, maxResults is translated into rownum by hibernate.

As for what uniqueResult() does, read its JavaDoc! Using uniqueResult instead of list() has no performance impact; if I recall correctly, the implementation of uniqueResult delegates to list().

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need an index on mytable.parent_id.

That should make your query fast enough, even for big tables (unless there are also a lot of rows with the same parent_id).

If not, you could write

```
select 1 from mytable where parent_id = :id and rownum < 2
```

which would return a single row containing 1, or no row at all. It does not need to count the rows, just find one and then quit. But this is Oracle-specific SQL (because of rownum), and you should rather not.

Comment: I'd go for an EXISTS query I think - more transparent to the requirement: select 1 from dual where exists (select 1 from mytable where parent_id = :id)

Answer (score 0):

For DB2 there is something like `select * from mytable where parent_id = ? fetch first 1 row only`. I assume that something similar exists for oracle.

Comment: All SQl dialects differ - you can't assume there are similar things e.g. Oracle has rownum which is not there in Sybase and I think in DB2

Comment: so the rownum concept is what I would call "similar" because it covers the same use case, i.e. get the top n records (http://www.petefreitag.com/item/59.cfm)

Comment: re: top n. One problem with rownum is that it is evaluated before any sorting is done, so it is not really "top" n.

Comment: But since sorting is irrelevant here, I see no reason this answer deserves a downvote. While it doesn't give the proper answer, it points into the right direction, and is hence helpful. Therefore, +1.

Comment: not voting either way, but for a question that specifically says "Oracle" I'd expect Oracle syntax only. IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return 1 if any record exists and 0 otherwise:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE ROWNUM < 2);
```

It could help when you need to check table data statistics, regardless table size and any performance issue.