# Fastest way to check if a materialized view contains any rows

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a materialized view on an Oracle 11g database that should contain many, many rows.

What's the fastest way of finding out if the view has any rows in it? I'm not interested in how many rows, just if it contains one or more rows.

I was doing a COUNT(*) query, but this is taking too long to run. Any suggestions?

Please note, this question is not entirely unlike this other question: [The fastest way to check if some records in a database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131168/the-fastest-way-to-check-if-some-records-in-a-database-table)

Comment: Do you have an auto_increment ID value in your table? If so, do a select where ID = 1?

Answer (score 1):

the referenced answer you gave will work for you or:

```
select /*+ NO_REWRITE */ count(*) from your_mview where rownum = 1;
```

which would stop scanning once it found 1 row.

Comment: I just tried this and it took 920 seconds(!). If this should be returning as soon as it finds one row, I think my problem is somewhere else... Thanks for your help @DazzaL.

Comment: @mattyB it could be your MVIEW table segment has had a lot of deletes done and the table has a lot of empty blocks at the start. are there no indexes on the MVIEW at all? if so are they on nullable or not nullable columns?

Comment: Might like to add a NO_REWRITE hint in there as well just in case.

Comment: @DavidAldridge thanks. Yeah, added just in case they are cascading MViews.